# Parsing html to retrieve data with no Tag

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this html as show below; I would like to use `JSOUP` to retrieve `TEXT 1 and TEXT 2`.

```
<html>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <body>
         <h3>Subheading 1 </h3>
              TEXT 1
         <h3> Subheading 2</h3>
              TEXT 2
    </body>
</html>
```

I really do not know how to call it because it doesn't have tags or id. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used JSOUP but from a brief look at the documentation ([JSOUP Documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)), you should be able to use standard javascript methods to navigate so doing something like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Elements headings = doc.getElementsByTag("h3");
for (Element heading : headings) {
   Element text=heading.nextElementSibling();
   String value=text.text();
}
```

Then value should have what you want. Note this is not tested and is just based on the documentation.